# Google Apps Script - Drive Permissions insert - Random error : The following items could not be shared

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is an excerpt of my Google Apps Script code

```
var edit = [];
...

if (edit.length > 0) {
  for (var ed=0; ed<edit.length; ed++) {
    try {
      Drive.Permissions.insert(
      {'role': 'writer',
      'type': 'user',
      'value': ''+edit[ed]+''
      },
      file.getId(),
      {
      'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
      });
    } catch (ePerm) {  
    MailApp.sendEmail(courrielcreator, "Subject error","\rBody error);
    }               
  }
}
```

My question :

It is quite common that I encounter the error below on one of the shares while when I do the sharing again it works !

"Error message: An internal error has occurred; The following items could not be shared"

An idea ? A suggestion ?
Thank you for your attention﻿

Answer (score 0):

Suggested workaround given in these threads [1](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/uLLGxKlFGHk/mlVeNQrfvggJ) and [2](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/g52yh-wpSVA) is to create a new copy of your spreadsheet then share it again. If it doesn't help, try signing out and clearing cache/cookies.

Comment: Hello abielita,
Thank you for your comment.On the other hand, I can not apply those provisions. Indeed, this is a script that continuously scans a GDrive tree and automatically transfers the documents deposited by several users. At this time, if a share can not be made, the creator of the document and the administrator are informed so that they can manually share.